# Javascript Animation Not Functioning Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I made this script for a "reel" that should move up or down on the click of an up or down arrow. However, I have two issues:

1)The up arrow moves it down and the down arrow moves it up
2)After it has executed once I am unable to execute it again, I receive an error saying it was unable to parse "top".

Any idea on why this might be happening? I pasted all the code below. it isn't pretty, but it has everything there.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tales of the Hartland: Homepage</title>

<style type="text/css">

/* ID DEFINITIONS */

#reelHolder {
    height: 750px;
    width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
}

#arrowDown {
    z-index:auto;
    position:relative;
    left:87.4%;
}

#arrowUp {
    z-index:auto;
    position:relative;
}

#reel {
    position: relative;
}

/*CLASS DEFINITIONS */

.banner {
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-600px;
}

.arrow {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.reeler {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-300px;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.break {
    height:0px;
}

.bigBreak {
    height:50px;
}

</style>


<script>
//REEL UP
function reelUp(elem) {

elem = document.getElementById(elem);

var down = 0;
var curLoc = elem.style.top;

function frame() {

    down++

    elem.style.top = down + curLoc + 'px';

    if (down == 300)
        clearInterval(id);
}

var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms

}

//REEL DOWN
function reelDown(elem) {

elem = document.getElementById(elem);

var down = 0;
var curLoc = elem.style.top;

function frame() {

down++


    elem.style.top = (-1 * down) + curLoc + 'px';

    if (down == 300)
        clearInterval(id);
}

var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <img src="Banner.png" width="1200" height="150" alt="" class="banner"/>

    <a id="arrowUp" class="arrow" href="javascript:reelUp('reel')">
        <img src="arrowUp.png" alt=""/>
    </a>

    <a id="arrowDown" class="arrow" href="javascript:reelDown('reel')">
        <img src="arrowDown.png" alt=""/>
    </a>

  <div id="reelHolder" class="centerDiv">


    <div id="reel">
        <img src="reel1.png" class="reeler" id="reel1"/>
        <div class="break"></div>
        <img src="reel2.png" class="reeler" id="reel2"/>
    </div>



  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still looking for help!

Answer (score 0):

Higher values of `elem.style.top` move an element further down in its container. If `top` is `10px`, then the top of the element is 10 pixels from the top of its container. If `top` is `100px`, then it's 90 pixels farther **down**.

So to move an element "up" in `reelUp`, **decrease** `top`:

```
elem.style.top = curLoc - down + 'px';
```

And to move it element "down" in `reelDown`, **increase** `top`:

```
elem.style.top = curLoc + down + 'px';
```

I haven't tried running your code, but after reading it I would imagine the reason it only works once is that the variable `id` isn't defined within the scope of the `frame` function. If you declare `var id` before `function frame()` then it should work.

Those are the answers to your specific questions. Once you have those under control, I'd suggest combining `reelUp` and `reelDown` into one function since they're largely identical (they'll differ by a single character: `+`/`-`).

Comment: Unfortunately, even changing the "+" to a "-" didn't change the direction of either one. Stil can't run it more than once without the parsing error.